# What's the translation of round-trip transactions or round-tripping (finance) in French?

Tags: traduction, finance

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-tripping_(finance):

> Round-tripping, also known as round-trip transactions or Lazy Susans, is defined by The Wall Street Journal as a form of barter that involves a company selling "an unused asset to another company, while at the same time agreeing to buy back the same or similar assets at about the same price."

[Example of use](https://www.ft.com/content/6d21addc-0a66-48b9-b8a3-42b5714f497f):

> The company had backdated sales, engaged in round-trip transactions with customers to compensate them for buying its software, and falsely dressed up lossmaking hardware transactions as software deals, he said.

What's the translation of round-trip transactions in French? Google Translate and Linguee weren't helpful. Google Translate suggests "transactions aller-retour" but I don't see this phrases used in finance.

Comment: Probably a case where people use the English term. OQLF has [some](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8870883/aller-et-retour) [suggestions](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/17022071/dette-achetee-avec-decote-et-revendue-a-sa-valeur-nominale) for finance, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Transactions circulaires* would be my choice to translate "Lazy Susan transactions" with ~1,000 attestations in Google. In contrast to half a dozen *transactions aller et retour* or variants therof (so they *are* attested) and, sadly if not unexpectedly, zero *transaction Suzanne-la-paresseuse*.

The Susan in question seems 100% US: the Brits practice (or perhaps, being Brits, practi**s**e) "bed & breakfast transactions" and "wash sales" in her stead. The Canadian Govt also offers "merry-go-round transactions", which is cute.

As noted by ninja*étoilé and commentors, the term usually applies to sales of stock rather than goods. In the present instance, you might also consider *ventes [simulées](https://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/simulation.php)*, *ventes fictives* or *fausse facturation*. Whichever way, computer hardware is *matériel informatique*.